# Word for the descending levels underneath a Manager/Senior Manager

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for the levels of hierarchy underneath an employee? This question is very similar to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278113/a-word-for-people-who-work-under-a-manager) but I'm looking for a general term for the levels themselves.

In a phrase the word would convey, "Tier levels underneath". Used in a sentence would be, "George the associate is 2 **tier levels underneath** Jane the senior manager".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a word indeed exists, see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-rung-on-of-the-ladder

Thus, it's "2 rungs below someone"

Answer (score 0):

How about "George the associate in middle management, is 2 levels underneath Jane, the senior manager".

Level
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/level

Middle Management
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/middle_management

Comment: Hoping for something more generic, like something to describe someone 2 levels below a CEO for instance wouldn't really be middle management

Comment: @Mackija it is generic, you could also say "Jane is 2 levels below the CEO" or "Jack, the post clerk, is 10 levels below George, the associate in middle management". I would tend to use "steps" rather than "levels" but that's more of a personal preference, both are clear.